# Using Python pywin32 to send keystrokes to interactive win32 console application

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32, win32com

So I have been trying to use Python `pywin32` package to send inputs to an interactive console based win32 exe which gives me a bunch of options when executed and based on the input keyed in by the user subsequent menus are displayed. After some reading around on the net I did try to execute the following code but it is still unable to send the input to the program, so if anyone has been able to achieve something similar, please let me know.

the code I have been trying is as follows:

```
import win32com.client
def main():
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shell.run('cmd /K cd "E:\\Documents and Settings\\Owner\\Desktop\\pds\\"   && CONVERT.EXE')
    shell.AppActivate('E:\\Documents and Settings\\Owner\\Desktop\\pds\\CONVERT.EXE')
    print("sending keys...")
    shell.SendKeys("trial.bin")
    shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: so as it turns out, the application i'm launching CONVERT.exe is creating a subprocess 'coz of which i'm unable to pass the keystrokes to this process.  SendKeys only passes keystrokes to processes which it has control over.

Answer (score 0):

I've made small improvement in [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) library. Now it can deal with console window like so:

```
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.Application.start('cmd.exe', wait_for_idle=False)
app.Window_().TypeKeys('cmd.exe /?{ENTER}', with_spaces=True, pause=0.1)
app.Window_().TypeKeys('{ENTER 7}', pause=0.1)
```